# programmatically change minibuffer size

Tags: emacs, elisp

The minibuffer usually takes one line of screen space.  I want to programmatically enlarge it.

I am not sure why the following does not work:

```
(window-resize (minibuffer-window) 10)
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

[I am using Emacs 24.3.1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```lisp
(setq resize-mini-windows nil)
(window-resize (minibuffer-window) 3)
```